# How to write mutually recursive functions within a let binding in SML?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I would like to do something like this:

```
fun f () =
    let
      fun a() = b()
    and
      fun b() = a()
    in
      ()
    end
```

where a and b are sensible mutually recursive functions.  However, this gives:

```
Error: syntax error: replacing  AND with  SEMICOLON
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Declaration of mutually recursive functions in SML is marked by a `fun ... and ...` block:

```
fun f () =
  let
    fun a() = b()
    and b() = a() (* There is no 'fun' keyword before b() *)
  in
    ()
  end
```

Comment: The interpreter got angry at 'local', but replacing local with let (ie, getting rid of the second fun in my code) seems to work. Thanks!